# Selecting Distinct Values from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio

Here is my code for my list:

```
    public static List<Int32> getValueFilterItems()
    {            
        List<Int32> gridValues = new List<Int32>();

        ASPxGridView gridViewPromo = (ASPxGridView)gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(4, "Value");

        int val = Convert.ToInt32(gridViewPromo);

        gridValues.Add(val);

        return gridValues;
    }
```

I want to return only DISTINCT values from the list as there many repetitive values.
How do i this?

Thanks

Comment: there is only one element in list

Comment: this function does not return more than one value in the list, howcome you are facing problem you posted, give details

Comment: are you sure when convert gridview to int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
return gridValues.Distinct().ToList()
```

A more efficient approach is using a `HashSet<Int32>`:

```
public static List<Int32> getValueFilterItems()
{            
    HashSet<Int32> values = new HashSet<Int32>();

    ASPxGridView gridViewPromo = (ASPxGridView)gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(4, "Value");

    int val = Convert.ToInt32(gridViewPromo);
    values.Add(val);
    return values.ToList();
}
```

**Edit**: You're also using `gridViewPromo` even if it's unitialized. You have to initialize it before you use it:

```
ASPxGridView gridViewPromo = (ASPxGridView) whateverYourGridIs;
int val = Convert.ToInt32(gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(4, "Value"));
```

Final note: why do you need a collection anyway if you select a single value?

Comment: i get error

'System.Linq.Queryable.Distinct<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>)'is a'method', which is not valid given the context

Comment: Ok i see what you mean about the hashset, but there is error and i dont know why: "Use of unassigned local variable 'gridviewpromo'"

Comment: @user2991718 line with error `ASPxGridView gridViewPromo = (ASPxGridView)gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(4, "Value");` try change it

Comment: @user2991718: I've  edited my answer to mention the `gridviewpromo` issue. But i don't know where the `GridView` is, that's why i've "used" `whateverYourGridIs`.

Comment: @user2991718: Then i don't understand why you need to cast at all (and what you want to cast). Use the grid directly: `Convert.ToInt32(gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(4, "Value"));`. The line that starts with `ASPxGridView` seems to be completely redundant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The list returns the same few values many times, i only want one of each value. e.g. it returns 3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1......


I only want 3,5 and 1 returned

Comment: @user2991718: Have you noticed that your method adds just one value to a collection? I'm not familiar with `ASPxGridView` and it's `GetRowValues` method. So you need to retrieve al values and after that apply `Disinct().ToList()` on that collection or add the single values of each row to a `HashSet<int>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, after retriveing the values i add them to hashset... 

I have implemented a for loop to go through each row, so it wont only get one value now...

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use:

```
 return gridValues.Distinct().ToList();
```

Although HashSet will not need either Distinct.

Your function does not return more than one value in the list , I suppose you are calling this function from outside something like this

```
HashSet<Int32> values = new HashSet<Int32>();
var value1 = getValueFilterItems(4, "Value");
var value2 = getValueFilterItems(5, "Value");

//HashSet returns true from Add method if element added, returns false if element already exists
values.Add(value1);
values.Add(value2);
```

Modified function should be with HashSet

```
public static Int32 getValueFilterItems(int visibleIndex, string fieldNames)
{            
    ASPxGridView gridViewPromo = (ASPxGridView)gridViewPromo.GetRowValues(visibleIndex,fieldNames);
    return Convert.ToInt32(gridViewPromo);
}
```

Comment: i get error 'System.Linq.Queryable.Distinct<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>)'is a'method', which is not valid given the context

Answer (score 0):

Change the return value as 
         `return gridValues.Distinct.ToList();`